# Adding binary numbers Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to add two binary numbers in python using a simple code. Can someone tell me why this isn't working? Thanks so much! I tried breaking the code down but when I break it down it all works separately. But of course when I put it together it doesn't work.

I'm a beginner in Python so explanations will certainly be appreciated. Thanks for the help!

```
#Enter numbers and define variables
number1=input("Enter 1st Binary Number:")
number2=input("Enter 2nd Binary Number:")
x1 = number1[0]
x2 = number1[1]
y1 = number2[0]
y2 = number2[1]

#Convert to integers from strings
int(x1)
int(x2)
int(y1)
int(y2)



#Digit 1 of answer and digit to be carried
if x1+y1==0:
  a1 = 0
  c1 = 0
if x1+y1==1:
  a1 = 1
  c1 = 0
if x1+y1==2:
  a1 = 0
  c1 = 1




#Digit 2 of answer and digit to be carried
if x2+y2+c1==0:
  a2=0
  c2=0
if x2+y2+c1==1:
  a2=1
  c2=0
if x2+y2+c1==2:
  a2=0
  c2=1
if x2+y2+c1==3:
  a2=1
  c2=1

#Digit 3 of answer
c2=a3

if a3==1:
  print ("a3" + "a2" + "a1")

if a3==0:
  print ("a2" + "a1")
```

The error it's giving is that c1 and a1 aren't defined.

Thanks again!

Comment: I would suggest initializing your variables near the top of the function to something. You are getting this error because all of the first 3 if statements are false, and therefore a1 and c1 never defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
#Convert to integers from strings
int(x1)
int(x2)
int(y1)
int(y2)
```

to

```
#Convert to integers from strings
x1 = int(x1)
x2 = int(x2)
y1 = int(y1)
y2 = int(y2)
```

Also you have not defined `a3`:

```
#Digit 3 of answer
c2=a3
```

If you want to print the value of the variables (might have to convert them to strings using str()), use

```
if a3==1:
  print (a3 + " " + a2 + " " + a3)

if a3==0:
  print (a2 + " " + a1)
```

If you want to add the variables, use:

```
if a3==1:
  print (a3 + a2 + a1)

if a3==0:
  print (a2 + a1)
```

instead of

```
if a3==1:
  print ("a3" + "a2" + "a1")

if a3==0:
  print ("a2" + "a1")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was so helpful! I really appreciate it!

Comment: sure no problem, If it solved your problem, please check this as answer so that it helps the rest of the SO community :)

Answer (score 3):

I will suggest simple code to add two binary numbers.

```
number1 = str(input("Enter 1st Binary Number"))
number2 = str(input("Enter 2nd Binary Number"))
intSum = int(number1, 2) + int(number2, 2)  #int() takes first argument as string
result = bin(intSum)[2:]  #remove 0b
print result
```

output

```
Enter 1st Binary Number1111
Enter 2nd Binary Number1010
11001
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways in python to add two binary numbers and print them. Below are the methods. (However I will be explaining your problem below)

**METHOD 1:**

```
number1=input("Enter 1st Binary Number:")
number2=input("Enter 2nd Binary Number:")

num1 =int(number1,2)  //Convert string to binary number **NOTE:** int('string',base) is the format
num2 = int(number2,2)

bin_num = bin(num1+num2)
print(bin_num)
print(str(bin_num)[2:] #just to remove the '0b'
```

output:

```
Enter 1st Binary Number:10
Enter 2nd Binary Number:01
0b11
11
```

**METHOD 2:**

```
number1=input("Enter 1st Binary Number:")
number2=input("Enter 2nd Binary Number:")

num1 =int(number1,2)
num2 = int(number2,2)
print("{0:b}".format(num1+num2))
```

output:

```
Enter 1st Binary Number:10
Enter 2nd Binary Number:01
0b11
11
```

**YOUR PROBLEM:**

You can declare them at the top of your program and then use them.

**Also** you have one more thing wrong,

```
int(x1)
int(x2)
int(y1)
int(y2)
```

These four lines do nothing. You are not changing the values in x1,x2,y1,y2 you are just calling `int()` them without modifying them. Do this instead,

```
x1=int(x1)
x2=int(x2)
x3=int(y1)
x4=int(y2)
```

Complete code:

```
a1=c1=a2=c2=a3=c3=0 #Declare and define them all `0`s at top
#Enter numbers and define variables
number1=input("Enter 1st Binary Number:")
number2=input("Enter 2nd Binary Number:")
x1 = number1[0]
x2 = number1[1]
y1 = number2[0]
y2 = number2[1]

#Convert to integers from strings
x1=int(x1)
x2=int(x2)
x3=int(y1)
x4=int(y2)



#Digit 1 of answer and digit to be carried
if x1+y1==0:
  a1 = 0
  c1 = 0
if x1+y1==1:
  a1 = 1
  c1 = 0
if x1+y1==2:
  a1 = 0
  c1 = 1




#Digit 2 of answer and digit to be carried

if x2+y2+c1==0:
  a2=0
  c2=0
if x2+y2+c1==1:
  a2=1
  c2=0
if x2+y2+c1==2:
  a2=0
  c2=1
if x2+y2+c1==3:
  a2=1
  c2=1

#Digit 3 of answer
c2=a3


if a3==1:
  print (a3 , a2, a1,sep='')

if a3==0:
  print (a2 , a1,sep='')
```

And finally the last lines won't print the values of `a1`,`a2` instead it will only print the strings. so **remove** the **double quotes**.

**NOTE:** I have given an extra parameter `sep=''` without it your output will have spaces between them. Like,

```
1 1
```

After `sep=''` you will get

```
11
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Also, I believe defining them in the if statement doesn't make them local. In Python, variables defined in if statements are global.

Answer (score 0):

Every other answers are correct. Few other points though.

1.You can combine conversion to integer and assignment at one step. Like:

```
x1 = int(number1[0])
x2 = int(number1[1])
y1 = int(number2[0])
y2 = int(number2[1])
```

2.While doing multiple conditional checks with the same variable set, it's a good idea to use `elif` if it is not harming your logic. In your case:

```
#Digit 1 of answer and digit to be carried
if x1+y1==0:
  a1 = 0
  c1 = 0
elif x1+y1==1:
  a1 = 1
  c1 = 0
elif x1+y1==2:
  a1 = 0
  c1 = 1
```

Because, `x1+y1==0`, `x1+y1==1`, `x1+y1==2` are not going to be true simultaneously. Similarly it can be applied for the digit 2 of the answer also.

3.The number of lines can be decreased with a pre-assignment.

```
a1 = c1 = 0
```

Then your digit 1 block will look like:

```
#Digit 1 of answer and digit to be carried
if x1+y1==1:
  a1 = 1
elif x1+y1==2:
  c1 = 1
```

Here, I removed the checking for `x1+y1==0`, because by default `a1` and `c1` are `0`. And for other invalid cases, you have to make another conditional statement. Digit 2 block also can be modified similarly.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to `Stackoverflow`. Avoid commenting like Thank you or +1 or something like that. If an answer is useful, simply upvote it. Again, welcome aboard.